# DOM Element Layout Changed Event

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I am wondering if there is a special DOM event that is triggered whenever an element needs to be re-layouted.

In my usecase, I want to display a "remove button" on a image. However, the position of the image is not fixed and I need to update the position of the button once the image is moved. For resizing, there are some jQuery plugins but I haven't found information how to listen to layout changes.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is causing the image to move in the first place. Also +1 for "re-layouted" :-)

Comment: hm, it is a "folder" of images and whenever I insert a new image, the other images might need to be "re-layouted" (sorry, had to do it again).

Comment: So, I could listen to the "add" event... But I was wondering if there is a more element-event-driven solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a DOM event that I know of, but one method would be to supply a function to setInterval to keep polling the position of the element, and act when it changes.

Comment: Yes, but then you face again the old balancing problem "speed" vs. "accuracy". I ended up with a solution where the actual event that is responsible for the re-layouting triggers another special event that other elements can listen to. Thanks!